# SQL - Percent of Grand Total of Each Partition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently using the below formula to calculate percent of total, but the formula is calculating as a moving percent of total per partition. Is there a way so the formula calculates over the overall total of each partition?

```
SELECT WINC_MAIN_DECAY.*, 
WINC_MAIN_DECAY.acquisition/NULLIF(SUM(acquisition) OVER(PARTITION BY master_show_name, spend_count ORDER BY master_date ASC),0) AS perc_total
FROM WINC_MAIN_DECAY
```

Results Below:

```
master_date master_show_name    spend     spend _count  acquisition   perc_total
   1/4/16         ABC           $101,010       1            10            1
   1/11/16        ABC                          1            10           0.5
   1/18/16        ABC                          1             5           0.2
   1/25/16        ABC                          1             2           0.074074074
   2/1/16         ABC                          1             1           0.035714286
   2/8/16         ABC                          1             2           0.066666667
   2/15/16        ABC                          1             1           0.032258065
   2/22/16        ABC           $101,010       2             6            1
   2/29/16        ABC                          2             3           0.333333333
   3/7/16         ABC           $101,010       3             5            1
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. So what would be the expected output comparing it to what you get now?

Comment: Example for row 1 would be: 10/31 = .32 since 10/(overall sum of first partition), row 3: 5/31 = .16

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a cumulative sum, but instead a straight-forward sum per partition, all you need to do is remove the `order by` clause from the `sum` window function.  In other words, instead of:

```
SUM(acquisition) OVER(PARTITION BY master_show_name, spend_count ORDER BY master_date ASC)
```

Change it to:

```
SUM(acquisition) OVER(PARTITION BY master_show_name, spend_count)
```